# How to append "_projected.shp" at the end of each dataset name

Tags: python, spyder, arcgis, projection

I have a code that projects a number of shapefiles in a folder to another coordinate system and the projected shapefiles are placed in another folder. For the projected shapefiles, I want to append "_projected" at the end each shapefile name.

What I have so far works for the projection and setting the output files into a specific folder, but the new output files are not showing the "_projected" at the end.

Here is my code

```
import arcpy
import os

arcpy.env.workspace = "inputdatafolder"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
outWorkspace = "outputdatafolder"

for infc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():
   dsc = arcpy.Describe(infc)
   if dsc.spatialReference.Name == "Unknown":
        print ("skipped this fc due to undefined coordinate system: "+ infc)

    else:
        outfc = os.path.join(outWorkspace, infc)

        outCS = arcpy.SpatialReference('NAD 1983 UTM Zone 10N')

        arcpy.Project_management(infc, outfc, outCS)

        infc = infc.replace(".shp","_projected.shp")
```

Since the code works, I am not getting any errors. The file name just isn't replaced with the ending I want it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is replacing the **text** of the filepath of `infc`, but not actually **renaming the file**.

Furthermore, `outfc` is the path to the new projected shapefile you are creating, while `infc` is the path to the original file. Don't you want `outfc` to have the `"_projected.shp"`suffix?

The code below changes the text of the output file path to include `"_projected.shp"` before calling `arcpy.Project_management` to create the new file.

```py
import arcpy
import os

arcpy.env.workspace = "inputdatafolder"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
outWorkspace = "outputdatafolder"

for infc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():
   dsc = arcpy.Describe(infc)
   if dsc.spatialReference.Name == "Unknown":
        print ("skipped this fc due to undefined coordinate system: "+ infc)
    else:
        outfc = os.path.join(outWorkspace, infc).replace(".shp","_projected.shp")
        outCS = arcpy.SpatialReference('NAD 1983 UTM Zone 10N')
        arcpy.Project_management(infc, outfc, outCS)
```

I'm also not sure if you're using `Describe` correctly. You may need to use `infc.name` when constructing the file paths.